# DateTimePickler - how change to earlier dates

Tags: jquery, forms, datetimepicker

Im using DateTimePicker for my jQuery UI project and it offers me dates between 2001 and 2040. How can i change it, so it offers me years from 1950 and on...

I tried min="1950-01-01" in input form, but it doesn't work.

**Code**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display month &amp; year menus</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1493/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi this only runs the code? what's the point?

Comment: Download that particular version http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/08/jquery-ui-1-8-16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [yearRange](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) option. This example will set the range to +/- 50 of the current year:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                              changeMonth: true,
                              changeYear: true, 
                              yearRange: "-50:+50"
                              });
```

You can also set it relative to the selected year or an absolute range.